# Como redirecionar a página somente após confirmação?

Tags: javascript, jquery

O usuário clicará num link e deverá aparecer uma mensagem de confirmação do tipo, "Realmente deseja acessar esta página?". Se ele confirmar, ele é redirecionado, se ele negar nada acontece.

Como posso fazer isto?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(evento) {
    confirm("tem certeza?");

    // E AGORA, COMO REDIRECIONO?
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://google.com">Ir para o Google.com</a>
```

Comment: o confirm já te retorna um boleano, caso não seja verdadeiro `evento.preventDefault()`; bloqueia o evento de seguir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu caso, como o elemento já é um *hyperlink*, é só capturar o retorno do `confirm` e prevenir o comportamento padrão do navegador (acessar o *link*) se o valor de retorno for `false`.

Tecnicamente isto não é um redirecionamento, é apenas um interrupção (caso usuário pressione o botão <kbd>Não</kbd>) do que aconteceria normalmente.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(evento) {

    if (!confirm("Tem certeza?"))
      evento.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://google.com">Ir para o Google.com</a>
```

Se quiser simular o comportamento de um redirecionamento http, previna o comportamento padrão do *browser* (novamente, visto que é um *hyperlink*) e use [**`window.location.replace`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location).

Pode também usar `window.location.href` (ou simplesmente `window.location`), mencionado na resposta do @[Paul Polidoro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/41403) , ambos fazem praticamente a mesma coisa que é navegar para a URL especificada.

A diferença é que `window.location.replace` não inclui a URL no histórico.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(evento) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("Tem certeza?"))
      window.location.replace($(this).attr('href'));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://google.com">Ir para o Google.com</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(evento){
        if(confirm("tem certeza?")){      
            window.location.href="http://www.google.com.br";
        }
    });
})
```